# Angular ng-include and links to the current URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have very weird problem with angular ng-include. Below is very simplified HTML code of my case:

```
<html>
<body ng-app>
<div class="header"><a href='http://www.mysite.org'>LOGO IMG HERE</a></div>
<div id="Ng-Module-Holder"><div ng-include='/template.html'></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem, is when currently opened page is homepage (www.mysite.org), then the logo link is not working. If instead of using ng-include I put HTML directly in module holder, then everything works as expected...

Does it hidden feature of angular or bug, or I miss something?

I use angular 1.2.14. Thanks

**EDIT:** To be clear...there no problems with template loading, the problem is with other links on the page that refer current page. When I do not use ng-include, there no problems with links. Unfortunately, I don't know how to create demo on plnkr or jsbin, current URL in iframe is "about:blank" and that works.

**EDIT 2:** I think I succeed to reproduce it on plnkr: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lqhajFWzE5qmvVnpXRlT?p=preview)

Comment: I'm unclear as to what isn't loading.. is it the ng-include='/template.html' ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct path for ng-include?

Comment: Can you create an example on jsbin.com or something ?

Comment: <body ng-app> - should be <body ng-app='nameOfApp'> ... also, I believe you need a controller

Comment: The templates loads without problems, everything looks fine, the only problem, that when I use ng-include, other links on page that reffer current page, are not working.

Comment: @EliteOctagon I have a controller, and I use manual bootstrap. I just show very simple example.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6cIQxM09a65nsM6uUxvw?p=preview - working example

Comment: @EliteOctagon the template loads fine, the problem is with links that outside of the template. I don't know how to reproduce exactly same thing on plnk or jsbin... :(

Comment: @EliteOctagon I think I succeed to reproduce it on plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lqhajFWzE5qmvVnpXRlT?p=preview